# Import multiple files as pandas dataframe with index for each file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am creating a pandas dataframe out of list of files and trying to add a column of indices (`day`) for each file in a dataframe. The code:

```
for file in list_of_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')
    df['day'] = []
    df['day'] = list_of_files.index(file)
    df2 = []
    df2.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(df2, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

The result I expect to get:

```
i SECCODE   BUYSELL TIME ORDERNO    ACTION  PRICE   VOLUME  TRADENO TRADEPRICE  day
0   18  SU25080RMFS1    B   100000000   18  1   97.5228 204 NaN NaN 0
1   19  SU26203RMFS8    B   100043856   19  1   98.8707 206 NaN NaN 0
2   20  SU26206RMFS1    B   103543575   20  1   97.1110 208 NaN NaN 0
3   184 SU26205RMFS3    S   100000000   184 1   93.0000 1   NaN NaN 1
4   185 SU26205RMFS3    S   100000000   185 1   93.1000 1   NaN NaN 1
```

The error I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-bb0a3bc69a9b> in <module>
      1 for file in list_of_files:
      2     df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')
----> 3     df['day'] = []
      4     df['day'] = list_of_files.index(file)
      5     df2 = []

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3368         else:
   3369             # set column
-> 3370             self._set_item(key, value)
   3371 
   3372     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3443 
   3444         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3445         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3446         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3447 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3628 
   3629             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3630             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3631             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3632                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    517 
    518     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 519         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
    520 
    521     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

If I remove `df['day'] = []` line, I simply get last index as index for all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you're looking for. Use `enumerate` while looping over files to access the index, and instead of using `df.append` in your loop, just create the final DataFrame at the end using `pd.concat` to concatenate a list of DataFrames:

```
dfs = []
for day, file in enumerate(list_of_files):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')
    df['day'] = day
    dfs.append(df)

final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```